# Installing 3rd party packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, java

I am using Ubuntu, and installing packages through the repositories is easy, APT does it all for you, but sometimes I need to install something over the internet.

99% of the time, these packages are tarballs. Everything that I read tells me to run configure, then make, then make install to build after I have extracted the archive either with the archive manager or with the tar command itself.

However, everything I have downloaded so far does not have a configure script written for it. Or atleast it appears that way.

For example, I just downloaded the JRE from Java's website, in the hopes that I could use the browser plug in. But the download instructions only cover unpacking the files and then making a symbolic link so you can access the plugin.

So, now I have this giant file in my /opt directory. Here are the contents of it:
[image]

To me it feels like bin, lib etc should be in different directories, Is this true or no?

I have the same situation with pretty much every tarball I download. This one doesn't apply, but for other files I would like to make the program available as a link on my desktop. But, again the install instructions only cover unpacking and leave me with a single directory, like to one above.

Do I just have to make links to the appropriate file in my desktop folder myself, if I want the Icon?

Should I just assume that files that need to be configured further will mention it in the install instructions, or come with a configure script?

**EDIT**: I know the JRE is available in the Repositories, but it exemplifies the problem, so please look at the general question, not just the part about the JRE.

Comment: Is there any reason why not installing the JRE from the repositories? Or any other package?

Comment: No this was the current example, I just checked the repos actually and found it, but I figured it served as good of an example as any. Other packages, like the newest version of eclipse and the "processing" programming language are not available in the repos

Answer (score 1):

Its useful to understand when you use a simple tarball, and when you compile (and what everything does)

The configure script is for software you compile, and may have compilation options involving additional libraries or the option to select a prefix. It also ensures you have everything you need to actually compile the script and generates a makefile. make uses the makefile to compile the program. *Traditionally* make install copies the compiled program and associated files to the right place, but I use checkinstall, which creates a deb and installs it. This also lets you share libraries and other neat things. A 'deb' or 'RPM' is simply software compiled for a specific distro and version with a sane set of settings, and the knowledge that you can pull in needed shared libraries and dependancies automagically

If you already have it compiled, and there's no options, and are running the software as a regular user, you might package everything, statically compiled. Its the linux equivilent of 'portable' software (in the thumbdrive sense, not the write once, compile nearly anywhere sense). It assumes your user doesn't need additional options, and everything just works (or you're too lazy to package it properly. It happens.

While the HFS is sort of mandatory for unix-likes, not everyone respects that. In this *specific* case, I suspect this packaging style allows for simple use of relative file paths, side by side installs of different versions of java, using the JAVA_HOME prefix and things like that. Its entirely intentional.